# gradle exclude transient dependency from project

Tags: java, gradle

In my build.gradle I have the following snipped:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':utils')
    compile (project(':cache')) {
        // excludings because of dropwizard conflicts
        exclude group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core'
        exclude group: 'javax.ws.rs'
        exclude group: 'com.codahale.metrics'
    }
```

but in fact the artifacts are not excluded I still end up with different jersey and metrics in my classpath. Ony if I put this in my cache/build.gradle it will compile and run.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.codahale.metrics'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core'
}
```

But then my cache project is broken because of missing dependencies which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had issues with this in the past, what worked was when I included `module:` explicitly along with the group. like so:

```
exclude group: 'commons-math3', module: 'commons-math3'
```

If you use configurations to exclude, you don't have to do it on all*, you can do it on just local project compile as :

```
compile.exclude group: 'commons-math3', module: 'commons-math3'
```

Comment: Interestingly this works in a gradle command line manner but my intellij is still not able to exclude the dependencies. Never the less I will accept this answer but also warn other users that this might not fully solve the problem.

Comment: is your intellij env setup to use a different version of gradle?